# Como generar archivos Excel en base a un template? (con interacción de usuario)

Tags: c#, jquery, excel

Buen dia, seguramente mi pregunta de seguro no es muy compleja, pero en este momento no logro concebirme una idea de como llevarlo a cabo:

En base a un template Excel quiero poder guardar X cantidad de datos en X ubicaciones. Esto es sencillo de hacer, lo que no logro imaginar es:

- Como generar un nuevo archivo con los datos guardardados (sin modificar el excel usado de template)
- Como permitirle al usuario elegir la ubicacion donde guardar el archivo y el nombre

Vi 2 formas de llevar a cabo la modificacion del excel pero no vi en ninguna parte un JQuery o algun cuadro de dialogo que permita interactuar con el usuario para hacer los 2 items mencionados.

Usando Closed XML:
http://www.variablenotfound.com/2013/03/generar-archivos-excel-como-un-senor.html

Codificando unicamente con C#:
http://www.eslomas.com/2005/09/rellenar-un-excel-desde-c/

¿Alguien podrá ayudarme?

Comment: Está bien que hayas incluido enlaces a lo que encontraste en tu búsqueda/investigación pero las preguntas deben ser autocontenidas, por lo que deberías incluir las partes más relevantes de esas referencias, en particular porque el material externo podría dejar de estar disponible.

Comment: Por favor, brinda el detalle del código fuente que te presenta problemas. De lo contrario, es como si fueses al médico y le dices "me duele el estómago", el médico te pregunta "¿qué fue lo último que comiste?" y respondes "me duele el estómago", vuelve a preguntarte "¿tienes alergias?" y la respuesta sigue siendo "me duele el estómago". Mientras más detalles expongas de tu pregunta (sobretodo detalles técnicos que es la finalidad de este sitio), más nos ayuda a ayudarte.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tambien lo resolvi, use JsPDF para la generacion del archivo, es mucho mas amigable para la generacion de archivos estandards.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con también? Sería bueno que incluyeras un enlace a la fuente de la solución y una breve descripción de cómo te ayudó a resolver el problema.

Comment: Mi voto negativo a tu pregunta / auto-respuesta ha sido por los motivos que te mencionó @Rubén, ya que sería más beneficioso si intentas completar tanto la pregunta como la respuesta con más información, para otro OP que se encuentre en la misma situación que la tuya.

Comment: Sos libre de ajusticiar a quien gustes. Si alguien necesita mas detalle de la solución la brindare, como lo hice en otros post, pero este no es el caso, nadie esta necesitando dicha info, de hecho estoy cerrando mi propia pregunta para no dejarla abierta dado que nadie se ha dignado a brindar una respuesta. Ojala seas así de bueno ayudando con respuestas, como lo sos ajusticiando gente.

Comment: Esta respuesta, en su estado actual, luce más como un comentario. Te recomiendo revisar [answer] y [qué es una respuesta aceptable](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/959/227) para comprender mejor cómo formular las respuestas. Si bien este framework JsPDF te ayuda a generar el archivo, la idea es que el conocimiento ayude a futuros usuarios que lean esta publicación.